# Charging capacitor moving with respect to the dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, maxwell-equations, dielectric

Suppose I am charging a capacitor, so that a magnetic field is generated. This capacitor is placed inside a dielectric material with permittivity $\epsilon$ and then it is moved parallel to it's plates relative to the dielectric. How will the magnetic field change compared to the case when the capacitor is stationary?

Answer (score 0):

Juste to be clear, the capacitor is within a dielectric box, and then you're moving it in? Is there a void between the capacitor and the box, or is there a conductor? Or is the capacitor and the dielectric in contact?

Let's start with the case of a void and no contact between the capacitor and the dielectric. If you move slightly (or a lot) the capacitor and then leave it steady, a first guess would be that the magnetic field on the side of the capacitor which is closer to a surface would be slightly stronger or weaker in reason of reflexion on the surface. There would also be edge effects due to the box inner edges, but mostly the change will come from the difference of dielectric factor (sorry I forgot the name in english) $\epsilon$ of the void vs the dielectric and how much is reflected.

However, I need to read and revise a lot of the basics as I've forgotten a lot of it. Hope it gives you a starting point for further reflections